# Assetic / Coffee script bug: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Assetic\Filter\CoffeeScriptFilter::setBare() i

Tags: symfony, coffeescript, assetic

I have just updated Symfony to the latest version (2.0.16) and i'm getting a weird Assetic / CoffeeScript bug in the compile.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Assetic\Filter\CoffeeScriptFilter::setBare() in/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 119`

That line contains this:
`$instance->setBare(NULL);`

I have tried manually clearing the cache but the problem still persists. Any ideas?

Edit: The paths in my config file are definitely correct:

```
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: true
filters:
    coffee:
        coffee: %kernel.root_dir%/../../../.nvm/v0.6.18/bin/coffee
        node: %kernel.root_dir%/../../../.nvm/v0.6.18/bin/node
        apply_to: "\.coffee$"
```

Edit 2:

The version in 2.0.15 deps and deps.lock works fine, the version in 2.0.16 doesn't.

```
#2.0.15 deps:
#[AsseticBundle]
git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
version=v1.0.1

#2.0.15 deps.lock
AsseticBundle v1.0.1

#2.0.16 deps
[AsseticBundle]
git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
version=origin/2.0

#2.0.16 deps.lock
AsseticBundle fbcbaf46df2aa143759319de205e1babcf7dd87d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still benefit from the changes in the last four months, you don't need to use an old version of AsseticBundle.

In the `deps.lock` file provided with Symfony2 v2.0.16, the AsseticBundle version is incorrect. Use this version instead in your `deps.lock` file:

[a926f5e81718bb920459ce3226ceb258ab3c1f05](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/commit/a926f5e81718bb920459ce3226ceb258ab3c1f05)

Alternatively, you may **omit** the AsseticBundle version from `deps.lock` since the latest commit in the 2.0 branch will work with Symfony2 v2.0.16. The AsseticBundle 2.0 branch is currently at a926f5e8, the same commit I mentioned above. But I gather the 2.0 branch should always with with Symfony 2.0.x.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the latest version of assetic. If you are using the former "deps" file method to manage your dependencies - make sure assetic is listed with the master/dev/head version.

Post your deps file when in doubt...

If you are using the [composer](http://getcomposer.org) method:

```
php composer.phar update
```

should finish the job.

If you are sure you have the latest version - clear your cache again ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! See my edit above, the version in 2.0.15 deps and deps.lock works fine, the version in 2.0.16 doesn't.

Comment: Okay: this looks like a bug in the AsseticBundle. In the latest version of assetic there is a method CoffeeScriptFilter::setBare(). It does not exist in 1.0.3 (which you are using). Possible solution: Remove the deps.lock for assetic (not the AsseticBundle) and update to the head version and try again. Or - file a bug report ;)

Comment: Thanks :-) I've already rolled back to the last version which fixes the issue. I'll post an issue on their github. Cheers.

Comment: Here's that issue: https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/94 . Thanks for filing it, Greg.